# The Number Of Uninsured Won’t Fall As Much As Expected

Tags: ellipsis

> Generous subsidies will be available for sick people and families with children who really need medical care to buy individual coverage, but healthy single people between the ages of twenty-six and forty, say, will still have a financial incentive to remain outside the system until they get ill, at which point they can sign up for coverage. *Consequently, the number of uninsured won’t fall as much **as expected**, and neither will prices*.
>
> [[New Yorker](https://www.newyorker.com/news/john-cassidy/obamacare-by-the-numbers-part-2/amp)]

Consider the following sentence, please:

1. *Consequently, the number of uninsured won’t fall as much **as expected**, and neither will prices.*

Can I write the bold as-clause like this also:

a) ...won’t fall as much as **it is/was** expected **to fall**.

b) ...won’t fall as much as **it is/was** expected.

c) ...won’t fall as much as **is/was** expected.

Comment: You can optionally include the verb (past or present tense, ***was, is*** partly depending on *exactly* what you mean). But it's not idiomatic to include the "dummy pronoun" in *as much as **it** was expected* when the context is a PASSIVE construction. If it was an ACTIVE verb context, you would ***need*** to have an actual subject (noun or pronoun), as in *...won't fall as much as **people / we** expect[ed]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, is "it" really a dummy pronoun there? Doesn't it refer to "the number of uninsured"?

Comment: I think in the examples with "to" (as much as it was expected to [fall]), it's not a dummy pronoun. But without the "to", (as much as it was expected.), it's a dummy.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, But "as much as" here implies a comparison, just like the comparison in: *John is **as (much) tall as** I am.* Am I right?

Comment: Sorry - it's not a "dummy" pronoun. But obviously it doesn't have a name, because *it's not supposed to be there in the first place*. Perhaps I should have just called it an *extraneous "it"* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*a) ...won’t fall as much as **it is/was** expected **to fall**.*

Yes, this is the deep meaning of the sentence before it was shortened to its surface form. Either "is" or "was" could be correct, with differences in meaning that I assume are clear to you.

*b) ...won’t fall as much as **it is/was** expected.*

In casual speech this might be OK, but it's more natural to say, "... as it is/was expected **to**."

*c) ...won’t fall as much as **is/was** expected.*

Yes, this is just a step between the original sentence and example a) where the auxiliary verb is included.